# Synchronize threads on per-item base

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, locking, semaphore

While this question is about the `MemoryCache` class, I can imagine the same need with a `Dictionary` or `ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd` where the `valueFactory`-lambda is also a lengthy operation.

In essence I want to synchronize/lock threads on a per-item base. I know `MemoryCache` is thread safe, but still, checking if an item exists and add the item when it doesn't exist, still needs to be synchronized.

Consider this sample code:

```
public class MyCache
{
    private static readonly MemoryCache cache = new MemoryCache(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

    public object Get(string id)
    {
        var cacheItem = cache.GetCachedItem(id);
        if (cacheItem != null) return cacheItem.Value;
        var item = this.CreateItem(id);
        cache.Add(id, item, new CacheItemPolicy
        {
            SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20)
        });
        return item;
    }

    private object CreateItem(string id)
    {
        // Lengthy operation, f.e. querying database or even external API
        return whateverCreatedObject;
    }
}
```

As you can see, we need to synchronize `cache.GetCachedItem` and `cache.Add`. But since `CreateItem` is a lengthy operation (hence the `MemoryCache`), I don't want to lock all threads as this code would do:

```
public object Get(string id)
{
    lock (cache)
    {
        var item = cache.GetCachedItem(id);
        if (item != null) return item.Value;
        cache.Add(id, this.CreateItem(id), new CacheItemPolicy
        {
            SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20)
        });
    }
}
```

Also, having no lock is not an options, as then we could have multiple threads calling `CreateItem` for the same `id`.

What I could do is create a unique named `Semaphore` per `id`, so locking happens on per-item basis. But this will be a system-resource killer, as we do not want to register +100K named semaphores on our system.

I'm sure I'm not the first that needs this kind of synchronization, but I didn't find any question/answer that fits this scenario.

My question is if someone can come up with a different, resource friendly approach for this problem?

**Update**

I've found [this `NamedReaderWriterLocker`](http://johnculviner.com/achieving-named-lock-locker-functionality-in-c-4-0) class that looks promising at first but is dangerous to use as two threads can potentially get a different `ReaderWriterLockSlim` instance for the same name when both threads get into the `ConcurrentDictionary`'s `valueFactory` at the same time. Maybe I can use this implementation with some additional lock inside the `GetLock` method.

Comment: `ConcurrentDictionary` uses `Try*`/`*Or*` patterns in its API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, `GetOrAdd` is kinda the same, but I bet `ConcurrentDictionary` also locks the complete dictionary while the add lambda `valueFactory` is executed, and does not use a per-key lock.

Comment: AFAIK, `ConcurrentDictionary` is lock-free.

Comment: Tested it and it's indeed lock free. The test shows that the `valueFactory` for a second `GetOrAdd` is also called, when the `valueFactory` for the first `GetOrAdd` is still in progress, even though we're trying to get the same item (same key). So, what I want is that the second `GetOrAdd` call waits for the first one to complete (but only if we're trying to get the same item of course).

Comment: "Waits" implies some locking. Without waiting there's a possibility to call value factory twice, you're absolutely right. I'm afraid, you have to choose between these two scenarios, regardless of implementation.

Comment: @HenkHolterman check [this sample](https://gist.github.com/huysentruitw/f6f10cc1e9a10f2ef9bd5ab18f0b4f47) code, where you will see that the valueFactory for `key1` is called twice while the first one is still sleeping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your key is a string, you could lock on `string.Intern(id)`.

MSDN documentation: [System.String.Intern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

i.e.

```
lock (string.Intern(id))
{
    var item = cache.GetCachedItem(id);
    if (item != null)
    {
        return item.Value;
    }

    cache.Add(id, this.CreateItem(id), new CacheItemPolicy
    {
        SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20)
    });

   return /* some value, this line was absent in the original code. */;
}
```

Comment: Had no idea about the existence of `string.Intern`, very interesting. On the other hand, I think this is a very tricky approach.

Comment: It is, and it will leave you with a memory overhead that doesn't go away until the process exits.

Comment: It is a rather solid approach, when you can be certain there is no other locking on these strings. The overhead should usually be acceptable.

Comment: I could prefix the id with the class name or unique key to avoid lock collisions.